# How to publish a document stored in SQL using the original file name as a valid Url?

Tags: c#, sql, sharepoint, iis

I have a database that stores PDF documents as a byte stream in a varbinary(max) column, The original document name is stored in a varchar column with the document extension and the primary key is a guid. (This schema is fixed, documents must reside in the database)

There are no problems retrieving the document as a stream and either writing to a temporary file or streaming directly to a web browser.

My question is how could the document also be exposed via a Url using it's original file name?

An good example of what I am trying to do is SharePoint, Under the covers SharePoint stores the files inside the SQL database and exposes the document as a Url (With original file extension) that can be directly opened with a browser.

eg:  http://WebServer/Documents/MyDocument.pdf

(The platform is SQL 2008, IIS 7.5, .NET 4, C#)

Comment: Thanks everyone for the awesome answers, will do some testing and share the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your site uses ASP.Net MVC you can just add controller for /Documents download file by name:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "GetFiles",
            "Documents/{fileName}",
            new
            {
                controller = "Files",
                action="GetFile",
            }
        );
```

And controller class:

```
    public class FilesController : Controller
{
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public ActionResult GetFile(string fileName)
    {...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Without** using MVC, you can use something called an [IHttpHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler.aspx)

This will allow you to process a request to a url in any manner you like.
You will add code in your web.config, like so:

```
<httpHandlers>
        <add verb="*" path="/documents/*.pdf" type="Documents.LoadDocument,NameSpace"/>
    </httpHandlers>
```

Then you will have a class `Namespace.Documents.LoadDocument`
That implements the IHttpHandler interface (just two methods, and one of them is simply a bool that states whether or not your object is thread safe)

There is information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972953.aspx) that describes how to serve dynamic content using the IHttpHandler.

I believe this is exactly what you're looking for. You will be able to load up the document from the database based on the actual http request.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `Content-Disposition` header to your response:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=original_name.pdf
```

Answer (score 1):

See [Download and Upload images from SQL Server via ASP.Net MVC](http://rusanu.com/2010/12/28/download-and-upload-images-from-sql-server-with-asp-net-mvc/) for a full example containing routing that maps an URL to a file in the database, efficient download using streams and also efficient upload using streams.

The routing part is relatively straight forward with MVC:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Media",
                "Media/{filename}",
                new { controller = "Media", action = "GetFile" },
                new { filename = @"[^/?*:;{}\\]+" });
```

but the other bits and pieces, specially the upload that uses correct streaming semantics, may be a bit more complex that one usually expects. Most samples simply ignore the issues and create an in-memory copy of the entire file before uploading it to the database.

The follow up [FILESTREAM MVC: Download and Upload images from SQL Server](http://rusanu.com/2011/02/06/filestream-mvc-download-and-upload-images-from-sql-server/) extends the article to cover FILESTREAM storage.